# Docker is it possible to mount two host directories to the same container directory?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm currently running a GUI application inside my docker container, and mounting the host's X11 display server to my Docker X11 display server in order to display on the host, but perform all rendering inside the container.

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=:10.0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw imageName /bin/bash
```

I was wondering if it's possible to mount two different locations on the host to the same path in the container.

For example, map the container's X11 output to both the host's X11 display, AS WELL AS a VNC server for remote viewing:

```
docker run -it -e DISPLAY=:10.0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw -v /tmp/vnc-server:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw imageName /bin/bash
```

Or a more general example would be:

```
docker run -it -v /folder1/on/host:/folder/on/container:rw -v /folder2/on/host:/folder/on/container:rw imageName /bin/bash
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd be absolutely gobsmacked if you could. What to do you when you have the same file in both locations? How do you decide which one wins, or how merge conflicts are resolved?

Comment: I've removed the second question, as *a)* It's a second question, and *b)* its arguably off-topic for SO anyway.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense and is what I figured. Is there any way to split the display output inside the container then? So that what's being written to hte X11 server in the container is also copied and displayed on a VNC server that's also inside the container?